# How to convert this regular expression into a format java can use?

Tags: java, regex

I want to use regular expressions to be able to parse a sequence like this...

```
ifelseifelseififif
```

Where every else needs an if but not every if needs an else. I plan on using this expression

```
((if)*+(ifelse)*)*
```

but I don't know how to convert that into the format that I can use in java. Could someone show me and break it down for me?

Comment: Your input seems ambiguous. It could be `if{}else{}if{}else{}if{}if{}if{}`, or it might be `if{}else{if{}else{}}if{}if{}if{}` or many other variations.

Comment: Well, you got a start - so try it: what happens? However, take the time to review regular expression qualifiers (`*+` is an invalid qualifier sequence, at least in Java) and anchoring. Regular expressions can [also be tested online](http://www.regextester.com).

Comment: That regex doesn't do what you want it to do.  I recommend using a tool like [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/) to help build your regex.  As far as the Java part goes, what have you tried?

Comment: What's wrong with the expression? It needs to literally match that text I put up there. I don't need to account for brackets. Everytime an else shows up, it must be preceded by an if, that's it.

Comment: @user2246674 - Anchoring isn't necessary if OP is planning to use `match()`. It has implied anchors at both ends.

Comment: Ok and really I'm just confused by what all the characters mean in java. I've been looking at this list http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm and I just am not sure what to use. It seems like everything is just for individual characters rather than a whole word like if and else

Comment: You should read the [documentation for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex logic we want to match:

`(if` if
`|` OR
`ifelse)` ifelse
`*` That token, 0 or more times.

`(if|ifelse)*`

This will match 0 or more if/elseifs.

If you need it to fill the entire string from start to end, e.g. no partial matches, put ^ before it and $ after it:

`^(if|ifelse)*$`

Please read http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for an introduction to regex syntax (for instance, `+` is not what you think it is in regexes), and use http://www.regexpal.com to test your regexes quickly in the browser.

Comment: I was just going to change it to (if|ifelse)*

Comment: @Ted Hopp Yeah I got it backwards, fixed

Answer (score 2):

You probably want: `((if)*|(ifelse)*)*`. The `|` means "or".

However, it's unclear what you hope to accomplish with this. Your input seems ambiguous. It could be

```
if {
} else {
}
if {
} else {
}
if {
}
if {
}
if{
}
```

or it might be

```
if {
} else {
    if {
    } else {
    }
}
if {
}
if {
}
if {
}
```

or many other variations.

Comment: I don't have to think of it that way. It just has to accept or reject that sequence I put up there and the only rule is that every else must be preceded by an if.

Comment: And I was trying to use + as an or, because that's how I learned it

Comment: @TylerPfaff - In a regex, `+` usually means "one or more." (Inside a character class like `[+-*/]` it simply means a literal `+`.) The construct `(X|Y)` means "either X or Y".

Comment: I gotcha, it was just always notated that way in my text book. thanks!

Comment: @Ted Hopp It's redundant to match `(X*|Y*)` if you're just going to match the whole thing `*` times anyway - Just `(X|Y)` would make for a more efficient regex.